# Ansible proxmox playbook stopped working for unknown reason

Tags: ansible, proxmox

some time ago I've created ansible playbook for provisioning of new VMs to proxmox environment in my homelab via ansible. The catch is that after reinstalling my proxmox nodes last week, ansible playbook responsible for cloning of my debian template stopped working for some reason.

My playbook looks like this:

```
- name: 010-cloning
  hosts: "{{ default_PVE }}"
  user: root
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    PVE_node: ""
    VM_name: ""
    VM_template: ""
    PV_user: ""
    PV_password: ""
    default_PVE: ""

  tasks:
  - name: Cloning VM from "{{ VM_template }}" with name "{{ VM_name }}"
    proxmox_kvm:
        api_user : "{{ PV_user }}"
        api_password: "{{ PV_password }}"
        api_host : "{{ PVE_node }}"
        clone: "{{ VM_template }}"
        name : "{{ VM_name }}"
        node : "{{ default_PVE }}"
```

For some unknown reason I'm getting this error:

```
TASK [Cloning VM from "debian-11-template" with name "validationrun"] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [prox1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "No VM with name validationrun found"}
```

Where *prox1* is my proxmox node, *debian-11-template* is my template and *validationrun* is name of the new VM. I've checked official ansible documentation for proxmox module and I've tried the very example of VM cloning, but with the same error - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/proxmox_kvm_module.html#examples

I've tried to run playbook with verbose parameter, but I've got basically the same error as I've already mentioned (I've hidden sensitive content):

```
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (1, b'\r\n{"failed": true, "msg": "No VM with name validationrun found", "invocation": {"module_args": {"api_user": "XXX", "api_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", "api_host": "prox1", "clone": "debian-11-template", "name": "validationrun", "node": "prox1", "validate_certs": false, "full": true, "state": "present", "timeout": 30, "update": false, "proxmox_default_behavior": "no_defaults", "api_token_id": null, "api_token_secret": null, "acpi": null, "agent": null, "args": null, "autostart": null, "balloon": null, "bios": null, "boot": null, "bootdisk": null, "cicustom": null, "cipassword": null, "citype": null, "ciuser": null, "cores": null, "cpu": null, "cpulimit": null, "cpuunits": null, "delete": null, "description": null, "digest": null, "efidisk0": null, "force": null, "format": null, "freeze": null, "hostpci": null, "hotplug": null, "hugepages": null, "ide": null, "ipconfig": null, "keyboard": null, "kvm": null, "localtime": null, "lock": null, "machine": null, "memory": null, "migrate_downtime": null, "migrate_speed": null, "nameservers": null, "net": null, "newid": null, "numa": null, "numa_enabled": null, "onboot": null, "ostype": null, "parallel": null, "pool": null, "protection": null, "reboot": null, "revert": null, "sata": null, "scsi": null, "scsihw": null, "serial": null, "searchdomains": null, "shares": null, "skiplock": null, "smbios": null, "snapname": null, "sockets": null, "sshkeys": null, "startdate": null, "startup": null, "storage": null, "tablet": null, "tags": null, "target": null, "tdf": null, "template": null, "vcpus": null, "vga": null, "virtio": null, "vmid": null, "watchdog": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed.\r\n')
```

Did somebody encountered similar issue or do you know how to fix it? I've been trying to find solution for couple of days without success.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Proxmox_kvm Ansible Module. I have the same issue with the same code.
I found this bugreport: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/4278 which has fixes link which are already merged. Should work again with the next release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Proxmox_kvm Ansible Module. I have the same issue with the same code.
I found this bugreport: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/4278, fixes are already merged but not released yet.

In the meantime I fixed this by installing the Ansible community.general collection following this manual: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository

To checkout the latest commit of the Collection, run:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install git+https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general.git,main
```

Afterwards the VM creation works as expected.

Comment: This looks exactly like my issue. Thank you! I've must missed it when I was googling for solution.